# Logitech M570 Trackball is too slow on Linux

Tags: linux, mouse, logitech-mouse, manjaro, trackball

Since my [Manjaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjaro) Linux uses libinput, the trackball (Logitech M570) has a slow mouse pointer (acceleration).

Adjusting it via the KDE GUI Panel for the mouse didn't work, even like adjusting at the command-line interface via [xinput](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xinput).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found *[Bug 1217881. Summary: Impossible to change trackball pointer speed](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1217881#c8)*, which suggests to create a hwdb-file to set up the right DPI for the mouse.

This even may not work, but it points me in the right direction. I am confused, because if I enter the xinput list, I get two entries:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M570                             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M570                             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

So I thought, maybe the first suggestion didn't work at Manjaro ([Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux)) Linux, because [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) found too many entries for the name of the mouse.

So I go on to search how to replace the "name:" Parameter in this command and found this GitHub page: *[dfu-utils-cross/eudev-3.1.5/hwdb/70-mouse.hwdb](https://github.com/arduino/dfu-utils-cross/blob/master/eudev-3.1.5/hwdb/70-mouse.hwdb)*

```
# if vid/pid is unavailable, use
# mouse:*:name:<name>:
# if name is unavailable, use
# mouse:<subsystem>:v<vid>p<pid>:*
#
# For example, the following 5 matches all match the same mouse:
# mouse:usb:v17efp6019:name:Lenovo Optical USB Mouse:
# mouse:usb:*:name:Lenovo Optical USB Mouse:
# mouse:usb:v17efp6019:*
# mouse:*:name:Lenovo Optical USB Mouse:
So I've done this, which work for me:

sudo /etc/udev/hwdb.d/99-m570.hwdb

# Logitech M570 trackball
mouse:usb:v046dp1028:name:*:
 MOUSE_DPI=540@167
```

Then do:

```
sudo udevadm hwdb --update Then restart X.
```

Changing the settings at the KDE Mouse GUI Settings panel still doesn't seem to have any effect, but the mouse pointer is faster than before.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of `xinput` commands, I realized, as other posts suggest:

- Step 1: Remove the ball
- **Step 2: Clean the sensor**
- Step 3: Clean everything else
- Step 4: Put the ball back in

This mouse is very prone to accumulate lots of dirt below the ball. Gently clean everything you can; **dirt blocking the optical sensor** may very probably be causing the slowness in
your mouse, preventing it from properly tracking the ball movements.

A little picture of my M580 for reference on how I left it for it to work for me:

[image]